# Anyway to Get Cookie Data from a different website

Tags: php, jquery

So I have 2 domains: http://domain1.com and http://domain2.com

domain1.com has a bunch of cookies for the user stored on it.

I want to access all of those cookies but from domain2.com (to keep them synchronized).

Is this possible in JQuery? I was thinking of making a Cookie php file and somehow connect to that file from domain2.php to pull all of the data in.

Thanks for any help

NOTE: These are NOT sub-domains but 2 completely different domains I Control

Comment: If both domain is from a same server, create a server side cookie and make it available for both of your websites.

Comment: You may wish to explain *why* you need to do this in case there is a non-cookie way of accommodating the root need.

Comment: Duplicate of [Reading cookies across different hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546592/reading-cookies-across-different-hosts)

Comment: That would be like allowing people to access other people's bank accounts from other debit cards.   it's security violation. but you could share data through database or server side file instead if you own both domains and servers

Answer (score 2):

In a strict sense? No. It isn't. In a more loose sense, yes it is.

If you're storing all of your data in cookies, you're actually storing the data in the *browser*, which means that jQuery, Prototype, Mootools... can't help you because of browser security (unless you can turn their browser into a server (might work with a Firefox extension (I swear, FF could be an OS if needs be...), but that would be gratuitous)).

I said that in a loose sense it is possible because PHP lets you do two very important things. First, it lets you store your session in a database, and second it lets you assign the session ID directly. It is possible, then, to have two servers point to the same DB and then share SESSION data by switching the user's session ID.

Answer (score 1):

no. this would violate the security model on which browser cookies operate.

to work around this you can implement an iframe (perhaps invisible to the user) on domain1.com which is served from domain2.com and pass data between the two sites with JS.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at a server-side solution, creating a common database that all sites can access. When the user logs in, generate a time-sensitive, IP-keyed token that can be passed from site to site either in GET or POST. Then, validate each request on token, IP, and time. The combination of the three will resolve most security concerns.

or you can look at this SO question for ideas its in .Net though [Store cookie for other site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367569/store-cookie-for-other-site)