# Get Cookie Value from browser using angular

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

How to get Entire Cookies from browser using angular

I tried with document.query but i able to only get current page cookie not able to get another page cookie

Comment: What do you mean with `Entire Cookies from browser` and `another page cookie`? Do you mean that when you are on your domain that you are able to get the cookies stored e.g. for `stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: yes i am expecting like that

Comment: Please explain why you want to achive this, many websites today will have "same-origin policy" active for their websites to prevent what you are trying to achive.

Comment: I have two website, which open in two tabs  now i try to get A tab cookies from B tab is it possible to get

Comment: If the websites are not related to each other then no. That would be a huge security problem if that would be possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anyway to Get Cookie Data from a different website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006562/anyway-to-get-cookie-data-from-a-different-website)